# Facebook login from IOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I created an IOS App to login with facebook and it sends invitation notification to my friends to install the app. I followed developer facebook [App Invite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios) and also created App link from same [source](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1064415783628492/?platform=app-links-host).

My application is working fine and i can send notification to my friends but the problem is my friends didn't get any notification that i send. My application event debugging screen shot is given bellow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can have missed some imperative configurations for this to work :

- Check that you put a `Canvas URL` in Facebook App developper page.
- Check that you put an `App Domains` URL on the same page.
- Of course you have to put a `Bundle ID` of your app.
- Also make sure that your app in not in Sandbox mode.

If all of this doesn't solve your issue, please send me a screenshot of your Facebook app configuration.

Comment: I set Bundle ID properly but i cant find Canvas URL that u specified.

Comment: Sorry I noticed that `Canvas URL` doesn't exist anymore in the interface. I think that `App Domains` is the replacement for it. Have you set it ?

Comment: I added my event debugging screen shot after run my application.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your Facebook app configuration instead (you'll have to hide some confidential informations)